# Try Catch, ModelState.IsValid, or Both?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, try-catch, modelstate

I am wondering, what is the best way to test for validity and errors in basic CRUD actions?

When I first used to generate scaffolded MVC controllers, they had something like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // do stuff
    return View("SuccessfulView")
}
// if we got this far something went wrong, redisplay
return View()
```

But now I get something like this:

```
try
{
    // do stuff
    return RedirectToAction("SuccessfulView");
}
catch
{
    return View();
}
```

Testing ModelState is not the same as testing for an exception, so I'm tempted to put them both in.

But then I wonder why MS didn't put both in when they updated the scaffolding code (which no doubt they did for a reason).

Plus, every basic action then starts to get become quite convoluted:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    try
    {
        // do stuff
        return RedirectToAction("SuccessfulView");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
// if we got this far something went wrong, redisplay
return View()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ModelState - Validates your ViewModel with the Data Annotations that you would've applied.

[TryCatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) - Will catch any exceptions which may occur in your code.

I say **BOTH!**

This is how,

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    try
    {
        // do stuff
        return View();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) // catches all exceptions
    {
        return View(ex.Message);
    }
}
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error");
return View(model);
```

Comment: Thanks SHemmelburg. I'm curious as to why MS would have dropped one from the scaffolding in place of the other, and whey they don't put in both by default. That would seem the obvious choice, unless I'm missing something (which is highly likely)

Comment: @Martin Hansen Lennox, I agree, maybe they will at some point but for now, as long as we know how to implement these features I think we'll be ok. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason MS doesn't include try/catch in the scaffolding is because there are other mechanisms already in place to handle exceptions. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/850062/Exception-handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC-methods-explaine) for a list of 6 different options available in Asp.NET MVC. MS probably doesn't want to prescribe a specific method and intends for the implementer to choose one for them self.